# How to add TomTom's traffic flow map images to Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I have a raster image from TomTom which shows traffic flow. The image is created after sending lat, long coordinates, that is one point to the GET serves with the zoom value, then I get the image title.

How to lay this image on the map in the right position?

Note: There is no Bounds available.

If I use L.tileLayer, I get repeated image see image:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried till now? One of the main policies of this site is that coding questions should include relevant existing code of what has been tried till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your last answer in the comments I understand you don't need an overlay; but you need to consume a raster tile service with the following templateURL:

```
https://api.tomtom.com/​/traffic​/map​/{versionNumber}​/tile​/flow​/{style}​/{zoom}​/{x}​/{y}.{mimeType}?key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

then your code should look like:

```js
L.tileLayer('https://api.tomtom.com/​/traffic​/map​/4​/tile​/flow​/absolute​/{z}​/{x}​/{y}.png?key=YOUR-API-KEY', 
   {attribution:'TOMTOM Traffic'}
).addTo(map);
```

and keep z, x, y as is within the curly braces

It you need some more help, please provide some code without your api key

Comment: I will try the code. give me 10 minuntes.

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but it did not work.  L.tileLayer('https://api.tomtom.com/​/traffic​/map​/4​/tile​/flow​/absolute​/' + zoom + '​/' + xy[0] + '​/' + xy[1] +'.png?key=*************',
        { attribution: 'TOMTOM Traffic' }
    ).addTo(mymap);

Comment: But if I download the image first then use:     L.tileLayer('http://localhost:55058/images/traficImages/' + xy[1] + '.png?{foo}',
        {
            foo: 'bar',
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'
        }).addTo(mymap);

Comment: then it will work but repeaters as shown int he first post.

Comment: the code you gave me, dos not show error, but I can not see the tomtom image, is it related to z-index

Comment: Leave the `{z}​/{x}​/{y}.png` alone, don't substitute those values in your own code.

Comment: working example : https://gist.github.com/tsamaya/0f2f38b50820b758af085a2b1680017c

Answer (score 0):

It is the right job for the ImageOverlay layer (https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#imageoverlay)

```js
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
    new L.LatLng(40.71222,-74.22655),
    new L.LatLng(40.77394,-74.12544));

var overlay = new L.ImageOverlay("https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg", bounds, {
    opacity: 0.5,
    interactive: true
});

map.addLayer(overlay);
```

only question is: do you have your TomTom image bounds ?

Comment: No there is no Bounds, that's the problem. And if I use  L.tileLayer, I get repeated image

Comment: I wish I can send you capture screen.

Comment: Which API are you using from TomTom ?

Comment: Trafic API, Raster Flow Tiles (https://developer.tomtom.com/traffic-api/traffic-api-documentation-traffic-flow/raster-flow-tiles)